# How to use request.form to get text from a ComboBox instead of value?

Tags: vbscript

I have a combobox named "cboCustomer" with this option:

`<option value ="CustomerID"> CustomerName </option>`

---

I can use `Request.form(cboCustomer)` to return the **value** of the combobox, which is `CustomerID`.

But how can I get the **text** of the combobox, `CustomerName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the problem is Label Text will not be posted to the server on post backs.

1.) There is a work around however, posted here from ScriptingGuy1: [Workaround](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/06/24/how-can-i-get-the-actual-text-of-a-list-box-or-dropdown-list-option.aspx)

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

    Sub TestSub
        For Each objOption in OptionChooser.Options
            If objOption.Selected Then
                Msgbox objOption.InnerText
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

</SCRIPT>

<body>

<select size="1" name="OptionChooser" onChange="TestSub">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

</body>
```

2.) In my particular case, I think it may be better to get the value from Request.Form(cboCustomer), which spits out a uniqueID, and make a call to the database with a stored procedure to get the corresponding CustomerName to that CustomerID. In my case, this would make it more readable, I think. Unfortunately I think this might be slower performance wise, but as I'm having trouble implementing the above code, it's another solution to think about if anyone else has trouble with the workaround.

Will edit if I find another solution, as both do not seem as straightforward as I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

So far, I could not understand your requirement to get the text of the selected option to the server. However, there is one other to do it:

- Add a hidden control to the form.
- Use the "onchange" event of JavaScript to detect change and trigger a JavaScript function.
  Use a script such as:

  `var dropDownControl= document.getElementById("dropDownId");
  var selectedText = dropDownControl.options[dropDownControl.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById("hiddenFieldId").value = selectedText;`

Now, you will be able to get the value from server end.

Note: MsgBox is a client side function and never works in server-side VB Script.